# Determine function of 90° intercept line given a point

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, trigonometry

[image]
Given a known linear function f(x) how can you determine a linear function g(x) when g(x) intercepts f(x),

- At a given point (x,y)
- The point of intercept (x,y) is at a 90° between f(x) and g(x)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let f(x)=mx+b. g(x) is perpendicular to f so it is of the form -1/m x + c

Using the point (x*,y*) on g(x) we end up with g(x) = -1/m(x-x*) + y*